# Button.onclick automatically triggers, then will not trigger again

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, event-handling

I have a script, which I'm using to try and display only one section of a webpage at a time.

`function showMe(id){ clearPage(); changeDisplay(id, "block"); console.log(id)}`

Currently, I'm using buttons to change which section is displayed.

```
var aBtn = document.getElementById("a-btn");
var otherBtn = document.getElementById("other-btn");
aBtn.onclick=showMe("a-btn-section-id");
otherBtn.onclick=showMe("other-btn-section-id");
```

However, when I load the page, the following happens:

1. I see the function attached to each button activate once in sequence in the console.
2. The page refuses to respond to further button inputs.

Testing with the console shows that showMe() and the functions it calls still all work properly. I'm sure I'm making a very basic, beginner mistake (which, hopefully, is why I can't find this problem when I Google/search StackOverflow/read event handling docs), but I'm at a loss for what that mistake is. Why would my script assume my buttons are clicked on load, and why won't it let me click them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function an assign the value to `onclick` property instead of attach the function, try defining your `onclick` property as:

```
aBtn.onclick=function(){showMe("a-btn-section-id");};
otherBtn.onclick=function(){showMe("other-btn-section-id");};
```

Try the follow jsfiddle:

```js
function showMe(id){ // some stuff..
  console.log(id)
}

var aBtn = document.getElementById("a-btn");
var otherBtn = document.getElementById("other-btn");
aBtn.onclick=function(){showMe("a-btn-section-id");};
otherBtn.onclick=function(){showMe("other-btn-section-id");};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="a-btn" id="a-btn"/>
<input type="button" value="other-btn" id="other-btn"/>
```

Hope this helps,